# Access not allowed for retrieving scripts

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jersey, csrf

I have a set of microservices that run behind a Netflix Zuul gateway, which implements OAUTH2 based security and issues a JWT to the browser after successful authentication.

All of the normal Spring MVC pages display fine, but I have one app that uses Jersey and JSP pages, where the Zuul server blocks retrieval of any CSS and JS files with a 401 error.

How would one go about to include the current user's JWT when browsing to the JSP page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@ page contentType="text/html" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

        <% 
    String selectionUri = (String) request.getAttribute("selectionUri");
    String removeUri = (String) request.getAttribute("removeUri");
%>

            <html>

            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
                <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}" />
                <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}" />
                <title>Smart Mine Treeview</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='../../static/css/bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.min.css'/>" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='../../static/css/bootstrap-treeview.css'/>" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='../../static/css/mimacs.css'/>" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='../../static/css/all.css'/>">
                <script src="<c:url value='../../static/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'/>"></script>
                <script src="<c:url value='../../static/js/bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.min.js'/>"></script>
                <script src="<c:url value='../../static/js/bootstrap-treeview.js'/>"></script>
                </head>

            <body onLoad='loadTreeview("<%= selectionUri %>")' style="background-color: transparent">
                <div id="myFrame" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="my-frame">
                        <div class="my-hdr my-title">Location Hierarchy</div>
                        <div id="treeview" class="treeview my-treeview"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>

            </html>
```

Accessing the page directly displays fine, but not through a proxy.
Requesting the resources with the links in the browser work. http://localhost:30111/my-app/static/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js, for example, can be retrieved successfully through the gateway hosted on port 30111.

Hence I'm assuming it is something to do whith the JSP pages not submitting the current user's credentials along with the request for the resources.

Any help on where to start looking?

Answer (score 0):

Removed Jersey from the client application and replaced with Spring Boot to get this working.

After learning more about the security, I realized that the Zuul server configures an Oauth2 authorization, Spring Boot style, using the application.yml.
This creates a bean to match the JSESSIONID from the browser with a token stored within the gateway's JwtTokenStore, and verifies authentication there before passing the request along, without the authorization header.
To resolve this, the gateway has a filter to add the authorization header from its store in a request filter, or configure the gateway to retain stateless sessions as illustrated [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-make-a-stateless-session-less-authenticatio) .